# Android moving from one app to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two separate apps. the packages are as follows:

> com.example.incrediblemachine.rnt
>
> com.example.incrediblemachine.palpal

i would like to do the following:

when clicked on a button on the rnt app, i want the palpal app to open.
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Quesition is duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android- Refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **getLaunchIntentForPackage** method in your Button onClick() . Before that install com.example.incrediblemachine.palpal app in device /emulator.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.incrediblemachine.palpal");
startActivity(launchIntent);

}
});
```